# I have old laptop and tryin to install anaconda 3 with python 3.9 on window. I got an error. Failed to crest menus”. What to do next?

Tags: python, anaconda

I’m trying to install anaconda 3 on python 3.9 for window 64 bit. Got error”Failed to creat menus” I already clicked “Retry”, Error still stay the same. What should I do next?